# sudo su - has a 5 minute delay should I pop back to original use

Tags: linux, pam

We are working with ROcky linux 8.6 -

when we type sudo su - we are prompted for login and we get to root user no problem.

if we type exit we go back to the original user as is expected.

If we type sudo su - directly again we are getting -

sudo: PAM account management error: Permission denied

we have to wait 5 minutes ( or logout and login ) to make it work.

Can anyone let us know what pam.d configuration may be required.  thanks

---

OK for those of you who asked me to use sudo -i -u root the SAME behavior happens.

```
[mlevine@bastionhostrl-101w ~]$ sudo -i -u root
[sudo] password for mlevine:
[root@bastionhostrl-101w ~]# exit
logout
[mlevine@bastionhostrl-101w ~]$ sudo -i -u root
sudo: PAM account management error: Permission denied
[mlevine@bastionhostrl-101w ~]$
```

this does not happen on Centos hosts we use.  WE login by ourselves - then escalate privileges to root this way.  So that is not the answer - and telling me something is silly is not helping.  that is just rude.

We do want to prompt passwords on multiple attempts like this.  We have no timestamp settings in out sudoers file.

listing in audit log at the time - looks like the faillock is spawning but I thought the password was good for 15 minutes?

```
type=SERVICE_START msg=audit(1695911994.060:721): pid=1 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='unit=user-runtime-dir@806425 comm="systemd" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=success'UID="root" AUID="unset"
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1695911994.087:722): arch=c000003e syscall=257 success=yes exit=7 a0=ffffff9c a1=563ce2ed1330 a2=2 a3=0 items=1 ppid=1 pid=4846 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="(systemd)" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" key="logins"ARCH=x86_64 SYSCALL=openat AUID="unset" UID="root" GID="root" EUID="root" SUID="root" FSUID="root" EGID="root" SGID="root" FSGID="root"
type=CWD msg=audit(1695911994.087:722): cwd="/"
type=PATH msg=audit(1695911994.087:722): item=0 name="/var/run/faillock/mlevine" inode=105544 dev=00:17 mode=0100600 ouid=806425 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=NORMAL cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0OUID="mlevine" OGID="root"
type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1695911994.087:722): proctitle="(systemd)"
type=USER_ACCT msg=audit(1695911994.090:723): pid=4846 uid=0 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 msg='op=PAM:accounting grantors=? acct="mlevine" exe="/usr/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? terminal=? res=failed'UID="root" AUID="unset"
```

I think this is the part of audit log that shows success then fail. Sorry if I seem uninformed - never ran into this issue in CEntos

---

contents of pam.d/su

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth           sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth            substack        system-auth
auth            include         postlogin
account         sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
account         include         system-auth
password        include         system-auth
session         include         system-auth
session         include         postlogin
session         optional        pam_xauth.so
```

my groups

```
uid=806425(mlevine) gid=200(unixusers) groups=200(unixusers),10(wheel),707(fndsysadmin),33004(aosysadmins),210039(dev_linux_syseng)
```

Comment: What happens in logs (especially security audit log)?

Comment: Why not just use `sudo -i`.  Using `sudo su -` is a bit silly.

Comment: @Zoredache: `sudo su - user` is more convenient to type than `sudo -i -u user`. Up to, probably, it could be good feature to sudo to detect such use (e.g. that the command being run is su) and act appropriately.

Comment: Do you face the same issue/behavior when "sudo -i" ? It looks like it is related to your PAM configuration. May you share the content of your /etc/pam.d/su file?

Comment: Sounds like an isue with the password re-prompt mechanism - see https://www.sudo.ws/docs/man/1.8.25/sudoers_timestamp.man/ - I believe this stores data at /var/run/sudo/ts by default but controlled by timestampdir in the sudoers file.